# Copy attachement of a Soap Request into TestStep request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm copying Soap Request of a project into a testCase with a load script (project level), it all went good, unless I discover that all attachment files were not copied.

Here's my script :

```
testsuite=project.addNewTestSuite("Suite")
testcase=testsuite.addNewTestCase("Case")

def iface= project.interfaces["Interface"]
def op = iface.operations["Operation"]

op.getRequestList().each { req ->

   def config=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory.createConfig(req,  req.getName())
   def newTestStep = testcase.addTestStep( config ); 
}
```

Is there a way to copy every request's attachment into it's testStep copy?

If I need to add manually my test suite, and use a setup script (to use context, runner ...) I'm ready to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to get all attachments from the request in your operation list and import each one in the new TestStep, something like this must works for your case:

```
req.attachments.each{ attach ->
    newTestStep.testRequest.importAttachment(attach)
}
```

All together in your code:

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
def testsuite= project.addNewTestSuite("Suite")
def testcase= testsuite.addNewTestCase("Case")

def iface= project.interfaces["Interface"]
def op = iface.operations["Operation"]

op.getRequestList().each { req ->
  def config=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory.createConfig(req,  req.getName())
  def newTestStep = testcase.addTestStep( config )

  req.attachments.each{ attach ->
    newTestStep.testRequest.importAttachment(attach)
  }
}
```

Comment: oouuhh I'm late then... thanks anyway for the feedback :)